# How can I use basic authentication with MobileServiceClient?

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services, mobileserviceclient

I'm using the azure mobile services sdk to do offline sync. I made my api so that it is protected with basic authentication using email and password.

How can I embed these credentials with the MobileServiceClient, so that whenever I call a method it has the correct auth credentials.

this is my existing code for the MobileServiceClient.

```
var handler = new AuthHandler();

        //TODO 1: Create our client
        //Create our client
        MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(Helpers.Keys.AzureServiceUrl, handler)
        {
            SerializerSettings = new MobileServiceJsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                CamelCasePropertyNames = true
            }
        };

        //assign mobile client to handler
        handler.Client = MobileService;

        MobileService.CurrentUser = new MobileServiceUser(Settings.UserId);
        MobileService.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken = Settings.AuthToken;
```

AuthHandler Class

```
class AuthHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public IMobileServiceClient Client { get; set; }
    private static readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
    private static bool isReauthenticating = false;
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //Clone the request in case we need to send it again
        var clonedRequest = await CloneRequest(request);
        var response = await base.SendAsync(clonedRequest, cancellationToken);

        //If the token is expired or is invalid, then we need to either refresh the token or prompt the user to log back in
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            if (isReauthenticating)
                return response;

            var service = DependencyService.Get<AzureService>();
            var client = new MobileServiceClient(Helpers.Keys.AzureServiceUrl, null);
            client.CurrentUser = new MobileServiceUser(Settings.UserId);
            client.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken = Settings.AuthToken;


            string authToken = client.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken;
            await semaphore.WaitAsync();
            //In case two threads enter this method at the same time, only one should do the refresh (or re-login), the other should just resend the request with an updated header.
            if (authToken != client.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken)  // token was already renewed
            {
                semaphore.Release();
                return await ResendRequest(client, request, cancellationToken);
            }

            isReauthenticating = true;
            bool gotNewToken = false;
            try
            {

                gotNewToken = await RefreshToken(client);


                //Otherwise if refreshing the token failed or Facebook\Twitter is being used, prompt the user to log back in via the login screen
                if (!gotNewToken)
                {
                    gotNewToken = await service.LoginAsync();
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Unable to refresh token: " + e);
            }
            finally
            {
                isReauthenticating = false;
                semaphore.Release();
            }


            if (gotNewToken)
            {
                if (!request.RequestUri.OriginalString.Contains("/.auth/me"))   //do not resend in this case since we're not using the return value of auth/me
                {
                    //Resend the request since the user has successfully logged in and return the response
                    return await ResendRequest(client, request, cancellationToken);
                }
            }
        }

        return response;
    }


    private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ResendRequest(IMobileServiceClient client, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Clone the request
        var clonedRequest = await CloneRequest(request);

        // Set the authentication header
        clonedRequest.Headers.Remove("X-ZUMO-AUTH");
        clonedRequest.Headers.Add("X-ZUMO-AUTH", client.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken);

        // Resend the request
        return await base.SendAsync(clonedRequest, cancellationToken);
    }

    private async Task<bool> RefreshToken(IMobileServiceClient client)
    {
        var authentication = DependencyService.Get<IAuthentication>();
        if (authentication == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Make sure the ServiceLocator has an instance of IAuthentication");
        }

        try
        {
            return await authentication.RefreshUser(client);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Unable to refresh user: " + e);
        }

        return false;
    }



    private async Task<HttpRequestMessage> CloneRequest(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var result = new HttpRequestMessage(request.Method, request.RequestUri);
        foreach (var header in request.Headers)
        {
            result.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
        }

        if (request.Content != null && request.Content.Headers.ContentType != null)
        {
            var requestBody = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var mediaType = request.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType;
            result.Content = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, mediaType);
            foreach (var header in request.Content.Headers)
            {
                if (!header.Key.Equals("Content-Type", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    result.Content.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I embed these credentials with the MobileServiceClient, so that whenever I call a method it has the correct auth credentials.

Per my understanding, the `AuthHandler` class could provide a method for setting the current valid user info after the user has successfully logged in with the correct email and password. Also, you need to cache the `AuthHandler` instance which is used to construct the `MobileServiceClient` instance, after user logged, you could embed the current user info into the `AuthHandler` instance.

If you are talking about providing a sign-in process with a username and password rather than using a social provider, you could just follow [Custom Authentication](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/custom/) for building your `CustomAuthController` to work with [App Service Authentication / Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview) (EasyAuth). For your client, you could use the following code for logging:

```
MobileServiceUser azureUser = await _client.LoginAsync("custom", JObject.FromObject(account));
```

Moreover, you need to cache the `MobileServiceAuthenticationToken` issued by your mobile app backend and manually valid the cached token and check the `exp` property of the JWT token under the `SendAsync` method of your `AuthHandler` class, and explicitly call `LoginAsync` with the cached user account for acquiring the new `MobileServiceAuthenticationToken` when the current token would be expired soon or has expired without asking the user to log in again. Detailed code sample, you could follow adrian hall's book about [Caching Tokens](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/realworld/#caching-tokens).

Or if you are talking about [Basic access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), you could also refer the previous part about embedding credentials into your `AuthHandler`. For your server-side, you could also add your custom `DelegatingHandler` to validate the authorization header and set the related Principal to `HttpContext.Current.User`. And you could initialize your `DelegatingHandler` under `Startup.MobileApp.cs` file as follows:

```
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new MessageHandlerBasicAuthentication());
```

Moreover, you could follow [Basic Authentication Using Message Handlers In Web API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/basic-authentication-using-message-handlers-in-web-api/).